# Emacs python echo command with elpy

Tags: python, emacs, elpy

I am using elpy to run python in emacs. When I press C-RET on a command in myfile.py, it prints the output of that command to the python shell below.

Is it possible for it to print `1+2` before printing the response `3`? I think it would be a bit easier to track my shell output that way.

[image: emacs]

Answer (score 0):

Assume a way to go would be advicing the commands which send the code. When `python-shell-send-region` takes "beg" and "end", advice could take that region into a print(...) before.